# SELECT from DB by Date but not full with day, month and year

Tags: mysql, sql, database, date

I have found something like:

```
SELECT * FROM POSTY WHERE MONTH(data_dodania) = 5 AND YEAR(data_dodania) = 2017
```

But it's a bit not what I was looking for. And Maybe it doesn't even exist.
That's why I have question, is it possible to do something like check data smarter?

Like `where date=201705` (first year, second month).

This one doesn't work I know I tried. But I typed this to show something I'm asking for.

Idk, `where date='May2017` or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use MySQL's [DATE_FORMAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) to format the date in whichever way you want. E.g. following query formats dates in `YYYYMM` format:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(data_dodania, '%Y%m')
FROM POSTY;
```

Now, if you have date in this format, you can use `DATE_FORMAT` in `WHERE` condition to filter the rows, e.g.:

```
SELECT *
FROM POSTY
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(data_dodania, '%Y%m') = '201705';
```

Similarly, format to print May2017 is `%M%Y` (documtation has a list of formats and examples).

Comment: @DarshanMehta I'm very weary about using this, as you're not able to use indexes when using functions like `DATE_FORMAT`. Each row needs to be row scanned, executed, and compared in order to select a range. No index can be used.

Comment: I know, I guess @KrystianPolska wants to format the date (or has a date in that format already), in which case, we need to use `DATE_FORMAT` function to compare.

Comment: Note however that such a WHERE clause cannot use an index, so it's generally better to use a range condition - as per another answer here

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do a query with a date, is to specify a range to look in. This will be able to utilize indexes on the `data_dodania` field. Using any functions will cause your query to use a ROW SCAN in order to execute the function and then compare values. I highly recommend using ranges:

```
SELECT * FROM POSTY WHERE data_dodania >= '2017-05-01' AND data_dodania <= '2017-05-31'
```

Another way is to use BETWEEN syntax (This is syntactically the same as above):

```
SELECT * FROM POSTY WHERE data_dodania BETWEEN '2017-05-01' AND '2017-06-01'
```